# How to make a folder and subfolder with `FileSystemObject.CreateFolder` at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject, create-directory

Top macro works, bottom one doesn't unless I run the top one first. How do I create folder & subfolder concurrently?

I'm trying to use `FileSystemObject.CreateFolder` to make a folder and subfolder at the same time. The top macro works and the bottom one dosen't. The bottom macro will successfully run if I run the top one first.

Go ahead guys, make me look like an idiot.

```
Sub MakeDir1() ' this macro works
    Dim DocPath As String
    DocPath = "E:\@Workorders\test\"  ' E:\@Workorders\ is an existing folder
    
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(DocPath) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (DocPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub MakeDir2() ' this macro throws an error at "FSO.CreateFolder (DocPath)"
    Dim DocPath As String
    DocPath = "E:\@Workorders\test\test2\"
    
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(DocPath) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (DocPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should correctly indent your code to make it more readable.

Comment: See link above your question.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Sub MakeDir3() ' this macro works

Dim DocPath As String, DocFolder1 As String
    DocPath = "E:\@Workorders\test\"
    DocFolder1 = "test2"
    
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(DocPath) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (DocPath)
            FSO.CreateFolder (DocPath & DocFolder1)
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is this meant to be the solution to your issue or an additional information to your question? If this is meant to be part of the question please remove that answer and edit your original question to include it there. If this is meant to be an Answer mark it as solved. Answers should olny inculde solutions to the original question. • Note that `CreateFolder` does only create 1 folder but not a `path` so the path needs to exist before you can create a folder there.